# My exported .mtl seems uncompleted

Tags: materials, displacement, webgl

So I created this basic material. I used a random image to do some displacement effect :

[image]

When I export my cube and open the .mtl generated, I don't see any image inside my .mtl :

```
# Blender MTL File: 'None'
# Material Count: 1

newmtl Material
Ns 323.999994
Ka 5.000000 5.000000 5.000000
Kd 0.019458 0.800000 0.006406
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.450000
d 1.000000
illum 3
```

How can I fix this ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

While the [.mtl format](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/mtl/) has options for defining displacement, the [obj exporter add-on currently doesn't support them](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/io_scene_obj/export_obj.py$118).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this feature coming ? I need it to import my object inside my webgl canvas.

Comment: @user88476 I'm not aware that this is planned. Based on your example you could achieve the same result with a normal map, you don't need to tessellate actual geometry for this use case.